# how to access the currently attached element of a jBox inside jBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jbox

I am using stephanwagner jBox to accomplish the following task.

I have a list link like:

```
<a href="#" rel="first" class="delete">Delete First</a>
<a href="#" rel="second" class="delete">Delete Second</a>
<a href="#" rel="third" class="delete">Delete Third</a>
<a href="#" rel="fourth" class="delete">Delete Fourth</a>
```

I am targeting these elements. On clicking them, shows me a confirmation to make sure if really want to delete something. But now matter which link I click, it always picks the first element in a row. I am using `confirm` with a callback function when pressed ok/yes.

Problem is, I am not able to get the currently clicked element. I used `$(this)`, still not working. I think inside jBox, this refers to jBox itself.

Below is how I started

```
new jBox('Confirm',{
    attach: $('.delete'),
    title: 'Confirmation dialogue box',
    content: 'Do you want to continue?'

    confirm: function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete-file',
            data:{
                'path': $(this).attr('rel')  // It obviously didnt work as it is always selecting the first element in a row.
            }

        });

    },

    cancel: function(){

    }

});
```

Comment: Are you sure that plugin can attach `jBox` to all the selected elements ? - `attach: $('.delete')`. I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modificate plugin code like this:
for example u load **jBox.all.js** in head section;
then make changes in line 2032 to replace code "this.options.confirm()" with this one: "this.options.confirm(**this.source**)"! So in confirm-handler u get clicked elm:

```
confirm: function(elm){
   console.log(elm.attr('id'));
}
```

Similarly u can fix this problem to other event-handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
$(.delete).each(function(){
new jBox('Confirm',{
    attach: $(this),
    title: 'Confirmation dialogue box',
    content: 'Do you want to continue?'

    confirm: function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete-file',
            data:{
                'path': $(this).attr('rel')  // It obviously didnt work as it is always selecting the first element in a row.
            }

        });

    },

    cancel: function(){

    }

});
})
```